# How to download images from a website that are running in a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the website:

http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa#
The images there are moving in a loop.

This is an example of a url of one image:

http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309171200&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa
In the middle there is time and date: 201309171200
I need somehow to parse the time and date automatic from each url.

To build some string for example:

"www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=" + parsedDateAndTime + &cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa
What i tried so far is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace DownloadImages
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int counter;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            counter = 0;

            string localFilename = @"d:\localpath\";
            while (true)
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile("http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa#", localFilename + counter.ToString("D6") + ".jpg");
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But i didn't parse any url yet im justing using the main loop url and i see that it's downloading each time 46kb file but i can't open them im getting an error that paint can't open it...etc

This is wrong the way i did it.

How can i download each image from the site from the loop ?

How can i parse from each image the date and time so it won't download the same image all the time ? I need somehow to get the date and tiem of each image-url and use it as a sign or something so it won't download the same file.

Edit**

The date and time are changing per url of each image for example :

http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309161500&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa

Next image url will be: http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309171500&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa

The date and time change according to the loop just as it is in the website if you make right click on the image and make: Copy image URL you can see the time and date are change per image.

Comment: you can not open the image because in your code you are downloading a gif file which your code gives a *.jpg extension

Comment: unless you improve the it, posting the same question twice will not help you much. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805142/how-can-i-download-images-from-a-website-that-is-loop

Comment: Put some more information . Like is date time is randomly used or fixed . And y you r changing the extension at this point . I thought you have to download original image and it will open properly

Comment: The date and time are fixed per url in the loop.

Comment: Changed the line made the extention gif: localFilename + counter.ToString("D6") + ".gif" still can't open the file same error.

Comment: Then why you want to put date time dynamically. If they are fixed . Use the same value from above url .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that you get a URL of the form:

```
"http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?
    jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309171500&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"
```

And you want to extract that date and time bit so you can compare it against a list of images that you already have. So in the above, you want to get the `201309171500`.

You can do that with a regular expression:

```
string theUrl = @"http://www.niederschlahttp://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?
    jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309171500&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa";

Match m = Regex.Match(theUrl, @"&datum=(\d{12})&");
if (m.Success)
{
    string theDate = m.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(theDate);
}
```

### Additional info

If you look at the HTML from the original URL, `http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1&continent=europa#`, you'll see some Javascript that looks like this:

```
var images = new Array(
    "http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=201309150000&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa",
    "http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?
    // many more image URLs here
);
```

You need to download the HTML page, find that array in the HTML, and parse out the URLs for the individual images. Then you can download each image in turn.

Comment: Jim yes but the problem is that on the website each time the url is different. The date and time are different on each image in the loop on the website. So i can't put in the variable theUrl fixed url with fixed date and time. That's the problem to get each time the next image url.

Comment: There is animation on the website: http://www.sat24.com/foreloop.aspx?type=1 and if i put my mouse on the image it self on the animation make right click and make copy image url im getting each time url with different date and time. i need to save/download the images in the loop . Im not sure if its possible but the variable theUrl should be something like "http://www.niederschlahttp://www.niederschlagsradar.de/images.aspx?
    jaar=-6&type=europa.precip&datum=" + datetimevariable + "&cultuur=en-GB&continent=europa"